# how can i make IOCTL calls in kernel mode (windows)

Tags: windows, driver, kernel, ioctl

In user mode IOCTL calls can be made via [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363219%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.
What can I use in kernel mode to issue IOCTL calls? I must use this inside a filesystem minifilter driver.

BACKGROUND
I am writing a [filesystem minifilter driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx), and I must issue IOCTL calls to storage devices to find out their serial number and capabilities (removable or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [FltDeviceIoControlFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542046(VS.85).aspx) or build and send IRP manually with [IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548318(VS.85).aspx)
and [IoCallDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548336(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Do I need to call `IoCompleteRequest` to free my IRP or the lower driver does it?

Comment: No, IRP is completed by one of the lower devices. And don't forget to check your driver with driver verifier tool!